# How to use custom eagerload method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following line

```
Shipment.find_shipments(company_id: current_company.id).includes(:customer, :recipient, :carrier_product, ...)
```

A shipment belongs to a carrier_product

Problem is, on the CarrierProduct model, it has a self-referencing association, ie, each product can store a carrier_product_id of it's owning product. This chain can be multiple links long

I then created the following method to fetch all the ancestors

```
def find_top_level_ancestors_from_ids(carrier_product_ids: [])
      self.where('carrier_products.id IN
                  (WITH RECURSIVE tree(id, parent_id) AS (
                     SELECT cp.id, cp.carrier_product_id FROM carrier_products cp
                     WHERE cp.id IN (?)
                   UNION ALL
                     SELECT cp.id, cp.carrier_product_id FROM carrier_products cp JOIN tree ON cp.id = tree.parent_id)
                    SELECT id FROM tree)', carrier_product_ids)
    end
```

I want to use the result of this method in the `.includes(:carrier_prouct)`, instead of the default, which only loads the first level of parents.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making a class level function. This can then be chained as much as you desire.

```
def self.find_top_level_ancestors_from_ids(carrier_product_ids: [])
  joins(:carrier_product).where('carrier_products.id IN
    (WITH RECURSIVE tree(id, parent_id) AS (
          SELECT cp.id, cp.carrier_product_id FROM carrier_products cp
          WHERE cp.id IN (?)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT cp.id, cp.carrier_product_id FROM carrier_products cp JOIN tree ON cp.id = tree.parent_id)
          SELECT id FROM tree)', carrier_product_ids)
end
```

*Note* the `self.` to make a class-level method.

This should allow you to do:

```
Shipment.find_shipments(company_id: current_company.id)
        .includes(:customer, :recipient, ...)
        .find_top_level_ancestors_from_ids(carrier_product_ids: [1,2,3,...])
```

Comment: forgot to mention, the `find_top_level_ancestors_from_ids` method is defined on a `CarrierProduct` model